# Compare parent and child fields' values in array after filtering

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

I have the following array of `parents` and `children` [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-u1sntg):

```
const parents = of(
  [
    { id: 1, type: 'A', children: [{ id: 3, type: 'A' }, { id: 4, type: 'C' }] },
    { id: 2, type: 'B', children: [{ id: 5, type: 'D' }, { id: 6, type: 'B' }] }
  ]);
```

I need to filter the `parent` where there is a `child` with `id` equal to 6:

```
{ id: 2, type: 'B', children: [{ id: 5, type: 'D' }, { id: 6, type: 'B' }] }
```

For that I used RxJs operators:

```
parents.pipe(
  flatMap(parents => parents),
  map(parent => parent.children.find(child => child.id == 6))
).subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

The output is the following `child`:

```
{id: 6, type: "B"}
```

But I need to get an **`Observable<boolean>`** which value is `true` if:

```
parent.type == child.type (In this case it would be true, e.g., 'B' == 'B')
```

I have been trying `FlatMap`, `Reduce`, `Filter`, `Find`, ...

But I am never able to end up with the `parent` so I can compare `parent` and `child` types.

```
{ id: 2, type: 'B', child: { id: 6, type: 'B' } }
```

Comment: do you need a boolean for each parent, or one for the whole set of parent. And if so, will it return true if all the parent have the same type or if only one does ?

Comment: does it need to be rxjs ?

Comment: @nicolas there will be only one child with id equal do 6 because ids are unique. So I will only need that parent and a Boolean for that parent.

Comment: so for all the parents you just need one boolean to see if there is one  parent has same type as their child?

Comment: @RenaldoBalaj yes, I would prefer to use RxJS

Comment: @FanCheung yes, only for one parent because before I compare the parent and child types I find the parent that has a child equal do 6. And there will be only one parent with that. In this case a child has only one parent and its is is unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace this: `parent.children.find(child => child.id == 6)`
with `parent.find(p => p.children.some(c => c.id === 6))` then instead of receiving `{id: 6, type: "B"}` you will receiver the parent with all children.

If you want to set only the child that has id 6 you can edit the line `map(parent => parent.children.find(child => child.id == 6))` with

```
 map(parent => {
   parent.child = parent.children.find(c => c.id === 6);
   return parent;
 })
```

After that instead of receiving `{id: 6, type: "B"}` you will get the parent with additional property child (parent.child) containing the child that has id 6. And then you can make the check parent.type === parent.child.type. Note that parent.child might be undefined so adding additional check would be necessary.

Comment: I do get the parent as you said but with both children. How can I compare the type of the parent with the child that has Id == 6?

Comment: Check the updated example with your suggestion: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-u1sntg

Comment: If you used the first appraoch you will need to run a find if you run the second approach it will be accessible under `parent.child`.

Comment: Got it ... I was able to make it work using the first approach using `map(parent => parent.type === parent.children.find(x => x.id === 6).type)`

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track, you just need to map your observable to a boolean, that check whether or not your child type will be equals to the parent type, we can reuse your current `map` and makes it returns a boolean instead of the child. We do that because we need both the parent and the child at the same time.

```
parents.pipe(
  flatMap(parents => parents),
  map(parent =>  {
    // we get the child with id 6
    let child = parent.children.find(child => child.id == 6)
    // we check if the child exists ( in the first case it does not )
    // we check if the parent type is equals to the child type.
    return child && parent.type === child.type;
  }),
).subscribe(x => console.log(x) /* true or false */);
```

I've forked / edited your [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-kr2dzm) with this fix.

Comment: Your code is not exactly what I am looking for ... When using `find(child => child.id == 6)` there will be only one child because all ids are unique and one child can only belong to one parent. So I do not want to return one boolean (true or false) per parent. I wan to find which parent has the child with ID = 6 and then return if parent type is equal to child type. And not to all parents ...

Answer (score 0):

Below code is tested and should work, and if you need to match some id you can do in `reduce` to add more conditions

```
import { from } from 'rxjs';
import {mergeMap,first,reduce,filter,last,defaultIfEmpty} from 'rxjs/operators'

const parents = 
  [
    { id: 1, type: 'A', children: [{ id: 3, type: 'A' }, { id: 4, type: 'C' }] },
    { id: 2, type: 'B', children: [{ id: 5, type: 'D' }, { id: 6, type: 'C' }] }
  ];
from(parents).pipe(
    mergeMap(parent=>from(parent.children).pipe(reduce((acc:any,child)=>{
         console.log(parent.type,child.type)
         if(acc) return acc
         return child.type===parent.type
    },false))),
    filter((bool:any)=>bool),
    defaultIfEmpty(false)
   ).subscribe(console.log)
```